# Can't compile PHP with Sybase

Tags: linux, php, debian, configuration, sybase

Trying to compile Sybase with PHP 5.4.13 in Linux version 3.2.0-4-686-pae (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.35-2

```
# apt-get install freetds-dev

php-5.4.13# ./configure --with-sybase-ct
...
...
checking Checking for ctpublic.h... configure: error: ctpublic.h missing!

# locate ctpublic.h
/usr/include/ctpublic.h
```

I've also tried

```
php-5.4.13# ./configure --with-sybase-ct=/usr/include
```

Same thing. No dice. I've search interwebs to no avail. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to look at the `config.log` file to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i literally JUST stumbled on the answer after posting:

```
--with-sybase-ct=shared,/usr
```

I know it's not a bug but this is where I found my answer:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13782

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the answer?